# How to display fields of an Object record in one column (one below other) in a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

This should be simple... I guess. I would like to display the fields of an Object record in one column (one below other) in a visualforce page. That is:
-Company Name- -ABC Company-
-Address- -123 Main St-
-Field 3 Description- -Field 3 Value-
-Field 4 Description- -Field 4 Value-
.
.
.
Similar to like how Salesforce displays in its native pages.

Currently I have all the field descriptions hardcoded as headers in a apex:column along with its value. It displays the data, but two problems:
1. It displays all the field values in one ROW with descriptions as headers. 
2. I hate to hardcode the field descriptions. Is there a way to programmatically pull that value? That is, if {Obj.field_value__c} pulls the value of the specified field, what is the syntax to pull its corresponding field description from Salesforce?

I would like to do this in a PageBlockTable, of course not using BR and TABLE tags. I am sure there is a cleaner way to do this... can someone tell me how?

EDIT: How to set the width to 100% when there are more than one such pageBlocks in a single row?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a custom controller cause you will need on. You can create a wrapper that stores the field description and value and then display it in a table using `<apex:repeat>`. What code do you have so far? You could also use a `pageblockSection` and set the column to 1 in order to display the field label and value in a single row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confused with your tags... `<apex:pageBlockTable>` is used for tables, for the regular UI style layout you want `<apex:pageBlock>` and `<apex:pageBlockSection>`.

Note the use of `columns="1"` in the section to get the layout you're after, and using `<apex:outputField>` takes care of the field label for us too. You'll need to use the right merge fields of course, but this should get you where you want to go:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="The Details">
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
    <apex:outputField value="{!Obj.Name}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Obj.Address__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Obj.Field_3__c}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!Obj.Field_4__c}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Perfect! I should have mentioned that I am a Salesforce rookie :)

Comment: On that note... I now have three such pageBlocks side-by-side. The field description is wrapping unnecessarily when there is quite some space after the field value. My point is, I would like the pageBlock to be relaxed (width = 100%), but neither pageBlock nor pageBlockSection support the width attribute. How could I accomplish that? See screenshot in OP.

Comment: Nevermind... I fixed it with tr and td tags. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't see the comments until now! You're right though, the standard UI only supports pageblocks at 100% width. When I've needed to do multiple I've either used a table like you say, or I've used the `styleClass` attribute to specify a CSS class which fixes the width.